# Занести данные в SQL циклом

Tags: c#, sql-server, 1с

Можете подсказать как занести данные в SQL циклом. Например: я получаю циклом данные из 1С и эти данные занести в SQL. Код который есть, ошибки не выдает, проходит, но в SQL данные не записались.

```
string conetcionString = @"Data Source=(server);Initial Catalog=Proverka;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=password";
sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(conetcionString);
sqlConnection.Open();
SqlTransaction transaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction();

SqlCommand command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
command.Transaction = transaction;

while (finish.Следующий())
{       
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Soglashenie] (Nomer, Kontragent, Sotrudnik) VALUES (@Nomer, @Kontragent, @Sotrudnik)";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Nomer", finish.Номер);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Kontragent", finish.Контрагент);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Sotrudnik", finish.Сотрудник);

    Console.WriteLine("Заполняем таблицу " + finish.Сотрудник + "");

}
transaction.Commit();

Console.WriteLine("ГОТОВО");
```

Comment: Собаки у имён параметров в `command.Parameters.AddWithValue` куда-то сбежали...

Comment: Поставил собаки, ничего не изменилось

Comment: Имхо, метка и упоминание 1С- это лишнее, так как у вы стянули данные и нужно их просто залить в MS SQL.

Comment: Поставьте брикпоинт на commit и убедитесь в том, что он выполняется.

Comment: Выдал - IsolationLevel "transaction.IsolationLevel" выдал исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" System.Data.IsolationLevel {System.InvalidOperationException}

Comment: А где какой-нибудь вызов типа command.ExecuteNonQuery()? Погоняли параметры по команде в цикле, а выполнить-то и забыли :)

Comment: finish.Следующий() а что это делает

Comment: Спасибо всем кто подсказывал. Denis Rubashkin ты прав, про ExecuteNonQuery() то и позабыл. Теперь все подгрузилось. finish.Следующий() прогоняет цикл из запроса в 1С.